# groovy build script to build a flex project

Tags: apache-flex, groovy, build, compilation, mxmlc

I am trying to build a flex (and java) project using a groovy build script. See documentation here - http://groovy.codehaus.org/Using+Ant+from+Groovy

I have the build working for the java project, but for some reason it does not work for the flex project. It fails because it could not create mxmlc task. My `flexTasks.jar` is in the $CLASSPATH environment variable.

What is wrong here? Has anyone ever done this kind of setup before?

Answer (score 1):

I'm writing a Gradle plugin to compile Flex that uses the existing Flex ANT tasks.  It handles multi-module builds with either compc or mxmlc and does correct build ordering based on dependencies.  As we're using Flashbuilder for development, the build uses property file sniffing to work out whether compc or mxmlc should be used.

My company are OK with open sourcing the plugin in the near future (probably on GitHub), so leave a comment if you or anyone else are interested.

**Update**

You can find the Gradle Flex plugin at GitHub [here](http://goo.gl/Mul9k) and and examples of using the plugin [here](http://goo.gl/xQYt5).